# Enable Mock Locations in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, android-6.0-marshmallow

I cannot get mock locations to work in Android Marshmallow. I have installed app in Android 6.0 . Now, When I want to set mock location for this app by following option.

> **Setting >> Developer Option >> Select Mock location app**

I can not see any Application to select.

Has anyone had success enabling mock locations under Marshmallow?

Answer (score 6):

If you use the Mock location permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Then you will be able to select your app by `Setting >> Developer Option >> Select Mock location app`

Comment: @DuannistonCardosoCabral If you add this line into your manifest (debug build), then you can select the  application which will use mock location.

Comment: Hi @xiaomi , I add this line to use ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION but it is not working, In the Setting >> Developer Option >> Select Mock location app . No app appear for me to choose . Can you have another way ?

Comment: @minh2611 strange, I tested with the emulator and a nexus 5 without trouble :/

Comment: @xiaomi, I tested on S6 device, I can not add it even I added 4 permission that android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS.                     I don`t know how I can select app on etting >> Developer Option >> Select Mock location

Comment: @minh2611 Is your build the debuggable build?

Comment: @xiaomi , I test for mock location function , but I see that, It can not run .

Comment: You have to run it and let it fail once before it's in the list of selectable applications.  Super-sucky for testing as the framework uninstalls the test app at the end of the tests :)

Comment: How to programmatically detect whether mock location app has been selected in Marshmallow?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. Even though my app's manifest file (debug build) had the required permission (ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION), the **Select Mock Location app showed no app in the list**.

**Solution:**

I started my application, pressed the home button (to send my app's activity to the background), and then navigated to Settings -> Developer Options -> Select Mock Location App. My app was now visible in the list.