# Enable Mock Locations and addTestProvider crashes in Android Marshmallow (v6)

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to enable mock location in my code, but could not make it work. It bascially crashes the app.

Here is what I did:

-- (using Android studio) I replicated AndroidManifest.xml from normal location to androidTest and test, with the following line added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

(btw, should I duplicate the whole AndroidManifest.xml under androidTest and test, or just have above line only?)

-- and my code crashes at the following place

```
 final String providerName = "MyWalkPokemonGPSProvider";
 private LocationManager mLocationManager;

 public void setMyGPS(){
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // this is where it crashes
    // if it is commented out, then it runs (but still does not allow MOCK)
    mLocationManager.addTestProvider(providerName, true, false, false, false, true, true, true,
            Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    Location loc = new Location(providerName);
    loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    loc.setLongitude(37.331784);
    loc.setLatitude(-121.885547);
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);
    new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}
```

btw, this code is inside a

```
public class OverlayShowingService extends Service { }
```

since I'm defining some overlay buttons here. (Update: for clarification, I declared the service in manifest.xml)

So, my questions are

1. when I run it (by commenting out the part that crashes), I still could not find the app under Setting --> Developer Option --> Mock location app. It is jut not listed there.

   I build the app by doing Build -> Generate Signed APK -> and use build type = debug.

   What did I do wrong here ? I tried suggestions under [Enable Mock Locations in Android Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755142/enable-mock-locations-in-android-marshmallow), but does not work
2. why mLocationManager.addTestProvider crashes ? Any suggestions ?

**Update**: for clarification, here is the manifest (for the test):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.michaelandjewel.walkmypokemon">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.michaelandjewel.walkmypokemon.OverlayShowingService"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your service in your manifest? You need to do so within `<application.../>`

I also had this line under addTestProvider in my previous project
`mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);`

Keep in mind that you also select which app you'll use for mock locations under developer settings (above about phone)

Comment: Yes, the service is declared in manifest. As stated, I could not find the app under the mock location setting, so I'm not able to select it.

Comment: any other suggestion? The addTestProvider still crashes the app.

Comment: You did also add the permissions for gps right? Fine and/or Coarse location and GPS provider

Comment: yes, I have the permission for the fine and corse location. What is the permmison for GPS provider ? I updated question above to show my manifest

Answer (score 0):

example **HOW TO**:

```
final String PROVIDER_NAME_GPS = android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

public void enableProvider(android.content.Context context, String providerName, int status) {
    android.location.LocationManager locationManager = getLocationManager(context);
    locationManager.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW, android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
    locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(providerName, status, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public void setLocation(android.content.Context context, String providerName, double latitude, double longitude, double altitude, float accuracy) {
    android.location.LocationManager locationManager = getLocationManager(context);
    android.location.Location loc = new android.location.Location(providerName);
    loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    loc.setAccuracy(accuracy);
    loc.setAltitude(altitude);
    loc.setSpeed(0);
    loc.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()); //System.nanoTime())
    loc.setLatitude(latitude);
    loc.setLongitude(longitude);
    locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);
}

public static LocationManager getLocationManager(Context context) {
    return (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
}

public void notifyForeground(Context context, SimpleLocation simpleLocation) {
    // set new location 
    setLocation(context, PROVIDER_NAME_GPS, simpleLocation.getLongitude(), simpleLocation.getLongitude(), ...);
    // notify via not manager we have new fix 
}

public static boolean isMockLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    return Secure.getString(contentResolver, "mock_location").equals("0");
}

private boolean _providerEnabled = false;

/**
 *   MAIN METHOD - ENABLE PROVIDER IF NOT ENABLED YET 
 *   PASS NEW FIX TO LOCATION MANAGER 
 */
protected boolean enableProviderAndNotify(android.content.Context context, SimpleLocation simpleLocation) 
   if (isMockLocationEnabled(context)) {
      if (!_providerEnabled) {
           enableProvider(context, PROVIDER_NAME_GPS, android.location.LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);
           _providerEnabled = true;
       }
       notifyForeground(context, simpleLocation);
       return true;
   } else {
       _providerEnabled = false;
       disableAll();
       warnNoMockLocationEnabled(context);
   }
   return false;
}
```

- to reveal app in developer settings select mock location app for api > M add in manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>`